# How to manage serialize / deserialize an enum property with Dart / Flutter to Firestore?

Tags: enums, dart, flutter

I need to store a Dart object from my Flutter application in Firestore

This object includes an enum property.

What is the best solution to serialize / deserialize this enum property ?

- As a String
- As an Int

I do not find any easy solution to do this.

Comment: Checkout `Vnum` https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_Vnum

Answer (score 90):

Flutter is able to generate JSON serialization code. The tutorial you can find [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#code-generation). It references the package [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation). It contains also support for enum serialization. So all you need, is use this tool and annotate your enum values with `@JsonValue`.

From the [code docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/json_annotation/lib/src/json_value.dart):

> An annotation used to specify how a enum value is serialized.

That's basically all. Let me now illustrate with a small example in code. Imagine an enum with vehicles:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

enum Vehicle {
  @JsonValue("bike") BIKE,
  @JsonValue("motor-bike") MOTOR_BIKE,
  @JsonValue("car") CAR,
  @JsonValue("truck") TRUCK,
}
```

Then you can use this enum in one of your model, for example `vehilce_owner.dart` that looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'vehicle_owner.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class VehicleOwner{
  final String name;
  final Vehicle vehicle;

  VehicleOwner(this.name, this.vehicle);

  factory VehicleOwner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$VehicleOwnerFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VehicleOwnerToJson(this);
}
```

This is what you need to provide according to the [json generation howto](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#code-generation). Now you need to run the builder or [watcher](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#generating-code-continuously) to let flutter generate the code:

```sh
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Then the generated code will look like as seen below. Take a look at the `_$VehicleEnumMap` that has been generated respecting your `@JsonValue` annotations:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'vehicle_owner.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

// more generated code omitted here ....

const _$VehicleEnumMap = {
  Vehicle.BIKE: 'bike',
  Vehicle.MOTOR_BIKE: 'motor-bike',
  Vehicle.CAR: 'car',
  Vehicle.TRUCK: 'truck',
};
```

Comment: @tbm98 glad to help

Comment: how to parse json string into enum back

Comment: Hi @NicholasJela, when you run `flutter pub run build_runner build` it will generate in the above example the vehicle_owner.g.dart it will generate methods both directions so also a method to parse the string into the value. The "trick" is to generate the serializer and deserializer methods not directly on the enum but for the class where you use those enums. Then flutter will generate inside the vehicle_owner.g.dart a method with the signature `K _$enumDecode<K, V>(
  Map<K, V> enumValues,
  Object? source, {
  K? unknownValue,
})` and handle the deserialization for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Adding to the above, typical usecase is to call `VehicleOwner.fromJson` in the service method where you get the VehicleOwner objects from. So for example you have a service method for REST calls like `Future<dynamic> getData(String url) {
  return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((val) { return Future.value(json.decode(val.body));
    });
}` (I omitted auth headers and error handling) and you call it in you VehicleOwnersService to get the data for one owner like that: `getData("yourUrlPath").then((value) {
          return VehicleOwner.fromJson(value)})` . This is a typical use case.

Answer (score 36):

## Latest enum implementation

In short, use the following latest implementation of enum serialization:

**fromJson**  -> YourEnum.**`values.byName("property")`**

**toJson**  -> YourEnum.property.**`name`**

### `toJson/fromJson` on your enum

Simply add those two functions to your enum and you are good to go. **Note that you could also simply create those functions in your class.**

```dart
enum Manufacturer {
  mercedes,
  volkswagen,
  toyota,
  ford;

  String toJson() => name;
  static Manufacturer fromJson(String json) => values.byName(json);
}
```

##### Example

```dart
class Car {
  final String name;
  final Manufacturer manufacturer;

  Car(this.name, this.manufacturer);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "manufacturer": manufacturer.toJson(), // Alternative: manufacturer.name
    };
  }

  static Car fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => Car(
        jsonData['name'],
        Manufacturer.fromJson(jsonData['manufacturer']), // Alternative: Manufacturer.values.byName(jsonData['manufacturer'])
      );
}
```

Comment: I like your use of the latest enum implementation (.name and .value.byName). Handrolling the json generation the json to/from is fine for such a simple thing as a you have, but I don't want to do so for a large object that includes enums. I would much rather use json_serializable. So, it seems to me that using annotations on the enum makes sense. Possibly I am missing something.

Comment: Very nice!
All within the dart api now. No more packages for such an easy thing :)

Comment: Any way I can extract the toJson() and fromJson() logic to a mixin so that they can be added easily to any enum? This will be helpful as the functions would be the exact same.

Comment: @KshitizKamal Although you could make an `extension EnumHelper on Enum`, its is not possible as far as I am aware to access the `YouEnum.values` in this generic class. You could though implement toJson() this way. You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1482#issuecomment-1345345728) issue where they are discussing to implement such functions into the native dart language.

Comment: @Paul Apologies, I didn't actually run the code, I just saw discussion of this problem elsewhere. Sorry for the out-of-date info!

Comment: Serialization has been an "interesting" journey with Dart. I hope that someday it settles down and all the misleading old docs go away.

Answer (score 14):

Gunter's answer is correct if a little incomplete.

JSON serializable does handle converting Enum's to and from a string, here is some example code of what is generated:

```dart
const _$HoursEnumMap = <Hours, dynamic>{
  Hours.FullTime: 'FullTime',
  Hours.PartTime: 'PartTime',
  Hours.Casual: 'Casual',
  Hours.Contract: 'Contract',
  Hours.Other: 'Other'
};
```

and in return it converts it back with this fairly obtuse function:

```dart
T _$enumDecode<T>(Map<T, dynamic> enumValues, dynamic source) {
  if (source == null) {
    throw ArgumentError('A value must be provided. Supported values: '
        '${enumValues.values.join(', ')}');
  }
  return enumValues.entries
      .singleWhere((e) => e.value == source,
          orElse: () => throw ArgumentError(
              '`$source` is not one of the supported values: '
              '${enumValues.values.join(', ')}'))
      .key;
}
```

I got so sick of this I decided to make a small package to take away the complexity, and it has come in pretty handy for me:

https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string

At the very least its unit tested over a copy/paste solution. Any additions or pull requests are welcome.

Comment: In case you use json generators as described here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#code-generation, then _$enumDecode is the auto generated method when it encounters enum values with @JsonValue. What would be really cool, if you could use  json_serializable and enum_to_string together to have a usecase as in Java with objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy()

Comment: Hey @Adam. I'm actually trying to extend json serializable at the moment to also generate a "populate" function so getting pretty deep in there. It's not a perfect solution but you can annotate a field with @JsonKey(toJson: (value)=>...) And similar with fromJson. That will allow you to handle the conversion manually and have different values if you need them.

Comment: Many thanks for plugging this nasty hole in dart. It's really sad that the top-voted answer is code-gen.

Comment: my use case is `enum Status { void }`, `void` is a reserved word in dart, but we have this value in other language system. In dart we declare the enum as `enum Status {
void_ }`, any suggestion how to handle this?

Answer (score 11):

The way i do it is by just saving the index of the enum.

Lets say you have an enum:

```
enum Location {
  EARTH,
  MOON,
  MARS,
}
```

and a class which holds the enum with following methods:

```
/// Returns a JSON like Map of this User object
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {
      "name": this.name,
      "location": this.location.index,
    };
  }

  /// Returns [Player] build from a map with informationen
  factory Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return new Player(
      name: parsedJson['name'],
      location: Location.values.elementAt(
        parsedJson['location'],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE**

After @JamesAllen answer regarding maintainability I came up with this new solution:

```
extension LocationExtension on Location {
  String get name => describeEnum(this);
}

Location parseLocation(final String locationName) {
  switch (locationName) {
    case 'earth':
      return Location.earth;
    case 'moon':
      return Location.moon;
    case 'mars':
      return Location.mars;
    default:
      throw Exception('$locationName is not a valid Location');
  }
}
```

In your toJson/fromJson do this:

```
/// Returns a JSON like Map of this User object
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    return {
      "name": this.name,
      "location": this.location.name,
    };
  }

  /// Returns [Player] build from a map with informationen
  factory Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return new Player(
      name: parsedJson['name'],
      location: parseLocation(parsedJson['location']),
    );
```

Comment: I really like this approach, especially with the new withConverter that came with cloud firestore 2.0.0!

Comment: The downside of this is maintainability: the next person to modify the enum (or maybe even yourself if it's a year later) might not know that the index and ordering is critically important. So for example if a value is added to the start of the list, you're totally screwed.

Comment: @JamesAllen Unit tests exists for a reason.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim Unit tests don't make up for writing brittle code.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone uses "Dart Data Class Generator". You need to annotate with // enum comment.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the enums integer value, because it is the easiest to convert from/to int/enum type.

You need to take care that you add new enum values only at the end when you modify the enum, otherwise persisted values will become invalid.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value provides code generation for classes and has its own enums and does JSON (de)serialization for you.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable seems to support Dart enums directly but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: "The best way is to use the enums integer value", followed by "You need to take care that you add new enum values only at the end [...] otherwise persisted values will become invalide" is contradicting to me.

Comment: I find enums in Dart quite limited as well. With the new extension methods it became more convenient to create from/to converters manually.

Comment: @Philippe Fanaro thanks for the edit suggestion, but I think it's better you add it as comment instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, [according to Joel Spolsky](https://youtu.be/yBDWgWBEbVQ), that kind of editing, the one that supposedly adds value (if mine was wrong, please do say so!), should be in the answer and not in the comments. The comment section should only be a discussion towards improvement of the answer; and he even intends on having comments disappear after a week in the future. I know it's just an opinion (he has specific reasons for it), but I was quite sold by it. Anyway, if you still disagree, I will post what I had in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jksevend's apporoach (saving enum Index), I solved it like this, which saves a readable string.
**Benefit**: You can insert new Enum entries between existing entries without breaking load/save!

```
class Player
{
    String name;
    Gender gender;

    // functions for jsonEncode and jsonDecode!
    Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        gender = getGenderEnum(json['gender']);

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      'name': name,
      'gender': getGenderText(gender);
    };
}
enum Gender
{
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    DIVERSE,
}
String getGenderText(Gender gen)
{
    switch(gen)
        case Gender.MALE:
            return "male";
        case Gender.FEMALE:
            return "female";
        case Gender.DIVERSE:
            return "diverse";
}
Gender getGenderEnum(String gen) {
    for (Gender candidate in Gender.values) {
        if (gen == getGenderText(candidate))
            return candidate;
    }
    return Gender.MALE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Dart 2.17 has been released you can now extend Enum class.

The trick is to assign a fixed/immutable value (int, string, whatever you prefer) used as the json representation.

```
enum Color {
  /// The [jsonValue] must not change in time!
  red(10), // Can be numbers
  blue(20),
  green("myGreen"), // Can be strings as well
  gray(40),
  yellow(50);

  final dynamic jsonValue;
  const Color(this.jsonValue);
  static Color fromValue(jsonValue) =>
      Color.values.singleWhere((i) => jsonValue == i.jsonValue);
}

main() {
  var myValue = Color.green.jsonValue;
  var myEnum = Color.fromValue(myValue);
  print(myEnum);
}
```

This concept and much more is already implemented within my new [jsonize](https://pub.dev/packages/jsonize) 1.4.0 package which allows to easily serialize Enums, DateTime and any of your own classes.
This is a simple enum example:

```
import 'package:jsonize/jsonize.dart';

enum Color with JsonizableEnum {
  red("rd"),
  blue("bl"),
  green("grn"),
  gray("gry"),
  yellow("yl");

  @override
  final dynamic jsonValue;
  const Color(this.jsonValue);
}

void main() {
  // Register your enum
  Jsonize.registerEnum(Color.values);

  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
    "my_num": 1,
    "my_str": "Hello!",
    "my_color": Color.green,
  };
  var jsonRep = Jsonize.toJson(myMap);
  var hereIsMyMap = Jsonize.fromJson(jsonRep);
  print(hereIsMyMap);
}
```

This is an extended example on [jsonize](https://pub.dev/packages/jsonize) capabilities:

```
import 'package:jsonize/jsonize.dart';

enum Color with JsonizableEnum {
  red("rd"),
  blue("bl"),
  green("grn"),
  gray("gry"),
  yellow("yl");

  @override
  final dynamic jsonValue;
  const Color(this.jsonValue);
}

class MyClass implements Jsonizable<MyClass> {
  String? str;
  MyClass([this.str]);
  factory MyClass.empty() => MyClass();

  // Jsonizable implementation
  @override
  String get jsonClassCode => "mc";
  @override
  dynamic toJson() => str;
  @override
  MyClass? fromJson(value) => MyClass(value);
}

void main() {
  // Register enums and classes
  Jsonize.registerEnum(Color.values);
  Jsonize.registerClass(MyClass.empty());

  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
    "my_num": 1,
    "my_str": "Hello!",
    "my_color": Color.green,
    "my_dt": DateTime.now(),
    "my_class": MyClass("here I am!")
  };
  var jsonRep = Jsonize.toJson(myMap);
  var hereIsMyMap = Jsonize.fromJson(jsonRep);
  print(hereIsMyMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While bootstrapping my first AWS Amplify project I found this interesting method in their own library:

```
// only to be used internally by amplify-flutter library
T? enumFromString<T>(String? key, List<T> values) =>
    values.firstWhereOrNull((v) => key == enumToString(v));
```

And it is invoked like this:

```
Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        type = enumFromString<PostCategory>(json['type'], PostCategory.values),
        ... // Other props
```

I have to admit, far more clever than my custom methods that used switches to read strings and output enums.  Now I know I will not be hired by big tech anytime soon...

```
// JSON deserialization
PostStatusE getPostStatusEnumByString(String type) {
  switch (type) {
    case "draft":
      return PostStatusE.draft;
      break;
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My favourite approach is to use the [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) package which has an `EnumClass` which allows annotations to control the serialized value. This seems like the safest and most robust solution because you completely separate the serialized value from the name of the enum or its index, allowing you to rename and reorder your enum values and not break you serialisation. For me this is a big win over a lot of the other answers here.

The downside is there's a little bit of setup. Add these to pubspec.yaml (replacing the versions with the latest available):

```yaml
dependencies:
   built_collection: ^5.1.1
   built_value: ^8.1.2

...

dev_dependencies:
   build_runner: ^2.1.4
   built_value_generator: ^8.1.2
```

Then write your enum like this - use the `wireNumber` annotation to tell it what integer value you want each enum to serialize to. Alternatively if you want to serialize to a string, replace this with `wireName`, eg `@BuiltValueEnumConst(wireName: 'foo')`

```dart
part 'my_enum.g.dart';

class MyEnum extends EnumClass {

  // Use wireNumber to serialise to an int, or wireName to serialise to a String
  @BuiltValueEnumConst(wireNumber: 0)
  static const MyEnum foo = _$foo;
  @BuiltValueEnumConst(wireNumber: 1)
  static const MyEnum bar = _$bar;

  const MyEnum._(String name) : super(name);

  static BuiltSet<MyEnum> get values => _$values;
  static MyEnum valueOf(String name) => _$valueOf(name);
  static Serializer<MyEnum> get serializer => _$myEnumSerializer;
}
```

You also need a file with the following (call it something like `enum_serializers.dart`):

```dart
library serializers;

import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';

part 'enum_serializers.g.dart';

// add all of the built value types that require serialization
@SerializersFor([
    MyEnum,
    // add any more enums you need serializing here
])


// Also add StandardJsonPlugin. Without this, it will by default output value lists instead of a JSON-compatible value map
final Serializers enumSerialisers = (_$enumSerializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

Then generate the companion `.g.dart` files:

> flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Now you can serialise and deserialise like this:

```
final enumValue = MyEnum.foo;

// serialize:
int serializedValue = enumSerialisers.serializeWith(MyEnum.serializer, enumValue) as int;
// deserialize:
EnumValue deserializedValue = enumSerialisers.deserializeWith(MyEnum.serializer, serializedValue) as EnumValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer, just add `JsonValue` like this:

```dart
enum Gender {
  @JsonValue('male')
  male,
  @JsonValue('female')
  female,
  @JsonValue('all_genders')
  allGenders,
}
```

If you are annotating an [enhanced enum](https://dart.dev/language/enums#declaring-enhanced-enums), you can use `JsonEnum.valueField` to specify the field to use for the serialized value.

Here is an example:

```dart
@JsonEnum(valueField: 'id')
enum OrderStatusEnum {

  @JsonValue('pending')
  pending(AppColors.kRed, 'pending', 'pending'),

  @JsonValue('done')
  done(AppColors.kSecondary, 'done', 'done'),

  @JsonValue('failed')
  failed(AppColors.kRed, 'failed', 'failed');

  const OrderStatusEnum(this.color, this._translationId, this.id);

  final Color color;
  final String _translationId;
  final String id;

  String getTranslation() => Tr.fromTranslationId(_translationId);
}
```