# Flutter freezed - what is @JsonValue for

Tags: flutter, flutter-freezed

I see you can do, for example

```
factory User({
  @JsonKey(name: 'home_address') String? homeAddress,
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_name') String firstName,
})
```

and the keys `home_address` and `first_name` from a json will be the properties `homeAddress` and `firstName` respectively.

But what is @JsonValue used for then?

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example code snippet including your question regarding @JsonValue?

Comment: I don't have an example because I don't know what it is used for, but it does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to serialize/deserialize an enum instance, as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/blob/master/json_annotation/lib/src/json_value.dart).

For an example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035817/how-to-manage-serialize-deserialize-an-enum-property-with-dart-flutter-to-fi).

Comment: So JsonKey to deserialize a class and JsonValue for enums? why are they different

Comment: You put JsonKey on a field, whereas you put JsonValue on an enum value to specify how that particular enum value should be serialized to/deserialized from