# Flutter encode and decode class fails

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a problem. I created the following class:

```
enum WeatherType {
  @JsonValue("sunny")
  sunny,
  @JsonValue("raining")
  raining
}

class Location {
  final String locationName;
  final String adres;
  final num? distance;
  final num windSpeed;
  final num windDirection;
  final String windIconColor;
  final num temperature;
  final WeatherType weatherType;
  TimeOfDay? arrivalTime;

  Location(
      {required this.locationName,
      required this.adres,
      required this.windSpeed,
      required this.windDirection,
      required this.temperature,
      required this.weatherType,
      required this.windIconColor,
      this.distance});

  Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : locationName = json['locationName'],
        adres = json['adres'],
        distance = json['distance'],
        windSpeed = json['windSpeed'],
        windDirection = json['windDirection'],
        windIconColor = json['windIconColor'],
        temperature = json['temperature'],
        weatherType = json['weatherType'],
        arrivalTime =
            TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.parse(json['arrivalTime']));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'locationName': locationName,
      'adres': adres,
      'distance': distance,
      'windSpeed': windSpeed,
      'windDirection': windDirection,
      'windIconColor': windIconColor,
      'temperature': temperature,
      'weatherType': weatherType.toString(),
      'arrivalTime': arrivalTime.toString(),
    };
  }
}
```

When I store this class as JSON string in the localstorage, it gets stored like this:

```
{"locationName":"Castricum aan Zee","adres":"Strand, 1901 NZ Castricum","distance":4,"windSpeed":12,"windDirection":90,"windIconColor":"76E648","temperature":5,"weatherType":"WeatherType.raining","arrivalTime":"TimeOfDay(23:20)"}
```

Then when I use the following line of code:

```
Location test = Location.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
```

The app freezes when running that `fromJson` method. What am I doing wrong in the encoding/decoding of my class?

Comment: what is the num type?  can you change that to float or int

Comment: There is wrong usage of `DateTime.parse()`. Check the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html).

Comment: @GoldenLion `num` mean it can be of type int or double.

Comment: use JSON.encode and JSON.decode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236629/what-is-the-best-way-to-serialize-deserialize-darts-new-enum-with-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for null in arrivalTime

```
 From Json:


 json['arrivalTime'] == null
        ? null
        : DateTime.parse(json['arrivalTime'] as String),

To Json:

'arrivalTime': instance.reviewDate?.toIso8601String(),


Enum 
enum WeatherType {
  sunny,
  raining
}
From JSON:
WeatherType  deserializedWeatherType = WeatherType.values.byName(jsonValue);


To JSON:

String jsonValue = weatherType.name;
```

Comment: The problem is the `ENUM` now. @MichaelHorn his solution worked for the arrivalTime

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of the way you're decoding `arrivalTime` - When you encode arrival time, you encode it as a string: `"TimeOfDay(23:20)"`. Then, when you decode it, you're using `DateTime.parse()`, which doesn't know how to parse that string.

To make your encoding compatible with your decoding, you can encode and decode the `TimeOfDay` in a more granular way:

```dart
Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : locationName = json['locationName'],
      adres = json['adres'],
      distance = json['distance'],
      windSpeed = json['windSpeed'],
      windDirection = json['windDirection'],
      windIconColor = json['windIconColor'],
      temperature = json['temperature'],
      weatherType = json['weatherType'],
      arrivalTime = TimeOfDay(
        hour: json['arrivalTime']['hour'],
        minute: json['arrivalTime']['minute'],
      );

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  return {
    'locationName': locationName,
    'adres': adres,
    'distance': distance,
    'windSpeed': windSpeed,
    'windDirection': windDirection,
    'windIconColor': windIconColor,
    'temperature': temperature,
    'weatherType': weatherType.toString(),
    'arrivalTime': {
      'hour': arrivalTime.hour,
      'minute': arrivalTime.minute,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Using a custom class, I get a lot of ambigious imports, because I now have 2 classes. The custom class doesn't have the methods `.now()`, `.format()`, etc. How can I fix that?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize `TimeOfDay` was a pre-existing class in Flutter. I've updated my answer to avoid that issue

Comment: The `TimeOfDay` was 1 of the errors and is fixed now, but I still get the freezing. When I comment out the weather type, it works, so something is going wrong when decoding that one. Do you know how to encode and decode the ENUM `WeatherType`?